# Facelets formatting/autoindent in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, facelets

How can I get formatting/autoindent working for Facelets pages? I have added JSF to my project facet in the project properties and that brings up the autocomplete for JSF tags, etc but I can't find the option to format/autoindent the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the same shortcut as you'd use on Java source files <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> works fine for me on Facelets files on Eclipse Indigo SR2. They'll be formatted according the XML syntax rules which you can configure in *Window > Preferences > XML > XML Files > Editor*. An alternative way to trigger this is rightclick the Facelets file and then choose *Source > Format*.

I'm also using the [JBoss Tools plugin](http://jboss.org/tools), but this feature isn't specific to the JBoss Tools plugin.

Comment: I got it working, thanks.  There was an option in the XML editor.

Comment: Are you implying that `Ctrl+Shift+F` didn't work for you? What Eclipse version are you using?